# lift-json serialization of case class hierarchy

Tags: scala, serialization, lift, class-hierarchy

I have a hierarchy like the following:

```
case class A(val a: Long, val b: String)

case class B(val c: String) extends A(a=3, b="a string")
```

and I'm trying to serialize it using lift-json ala the following:

```
val obj = B(c="another string")
val cameraJson = net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write(obj)
```

but what I'm seeing is that it only serializes the properties in class B and not those in A.

I've also tried:

```
compact(render(decompose(obj)))
```

with the same result

What gives?   Is there something obvious in Scala that I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

case class inheritance is a deprecated feature of Scala. This should work for instance:

```
trait A { val a: Long; val b: String }
case class B(a: Long = 3, b: String = "a string", c: String) extends A

val obj = B(c="another string")
var ser = Serialization.write(obj)
Serialization.read[B](ser)
```

Comment: A minor precision: It's case to case class inheritance that is deprecated. You can still extends a case class with a standard class.

Answer (score 5):

Classic lift JSON serialisation for case classes is based on constructor argument list (see [decompose implementation](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/core/json/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/json/Extraction.scala#L86)), not class attributes. So you have to either override all fields declared in the parent trait (as in the @Joni answer) or use composition instead of inheritance.

For example:

```
case class A(a: Long, b: String)
case class B(c: String, a: A = A(a=3, b="a string"))
B(c="another string")
```

BTW `val` keyword in case class constructor is unnecessary. The accessors for every constructor arg is one of the [things](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/258) you are getting for free by declaring class as a case.

Comment: It's more helpful to say that in case classes all constructor args are vals by default.

Answer (score 3):

IMO serializing only c seems like the right thing to do. The info appearing in serialization will be that the type is B and the value of C. Values of a and b are implied by the info type is B. They are 3 and "a string", and can be nothing else, so they do not need to be written.

From maybe too cursory a look at [the source code](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/core/json/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/json/Extraction.scala), the default behavior of is to serialize fields that correspond to parameters of the primary constructor